# How can I instruct the parser not to continue processing unterminated comments?

Tags: bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I'm working on improving error reporting on my compiler assignment. I'm handling unterminated comments in Flex using the following code:

```
<INITIAL>"/*"       {BEGIN(COMMENT);}
<COMMENT>"*/"       {BEGIN(INITIAL);}
<COMMENT>([^*]|\n)+   {}
<COMMENT><<EOF>>    {yyerror("UNTERMINATED COMMENT"); BEGIN(INITIAL);}
```

The issue is that the parser is printing its error message as well:

```
 $ ./comp tests/comments.cf 
 ERROR: UNTERMINATED COMMENT: 27
 ERROR: syntax error: 27
```

How can I instruct the parser not to continue its work? Adding an `exit` after  `BEGIN(INITIAL)` gives me what I want, but it does not seem to be the way to deal with it.

Comment: By the way, your `<COMMENT>` rules are not correct; no rule matches a `*` inside a comment, so that will fall through to the default rule. If your default rule is `. { return yytext[0]; }`, that will have particularly disastrous consequences; if the default rule is the flex-generated default (`ECHO`), it will just be weird. Also, the character set `[^*]` includes `\n`, so `|\n` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should certainly return 0 (or something) from the `<<EOF>>` action, because if you don't, the lexer will try to continue scanning (which is undefined behaviour; a scanner should not continue to read input after an EOF has been signalled, unless it has arranged for there to be a new input buffer.)

It is certainly likely that an unterminated comment will result in a syntax error, since the end of the program has most likely been swallowed in the comment. If you don't want this error to be reported, then you could simply set a flag which `yyerror` checks before printing an error message. In this simple case, there would be no need to reset that flag, since the unterminated comment error can only occur at the end of input, and no error recovery is possible at that point.

Bison itself has a mechanism to reduce spurious error reporting by suppressing "syntax error" calls to `yyerror` for three tokens after a syntax error is reported. There is limited access to this feature from within parser actions, but no access from outside of the parser so it cannot be enabled from a scanner action.

If you want a solution with a cleaner interface between the scanner and the parser, you might consider the following possibility:

1. In your lexer, when an unterminated comment is detected, return an otherwise unused token, say UNTERMINATED_COMMENT.
2. When the parser receives an UNTERMINATED_COMMENT token, it will immediately signal a syntax error (or almost immediately. Under some circumstances, it may perform some reductions before it even checks what the lookahead token is.) When `yyerror` is called, the value of the `yychar` global will be the lookahead token, so it will be `UNTERMINATED_COMMENT`; `yyerror` can use this fact to produce a more precise error message, rather than the generic "syntax error".
3. It is important to immediately terminate the parse at this point, since calling the scanner again will be undefined behaviour. That can be done by setting `yychar` to `YYEOF` in the `yyerror` function. (An alternative would be to include an error production with `UNTERMINATED_COMMENT` in the rhs, whose action is YYABORT.)